# How to re render table component upon receiving a notification from web socket in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, web-component

Im using React table and loading a page which displays a table with data fetched from an API. Im also listening on a web socket and right now, whenever something is sent over a web socket, Im printing a console message. Now I want to reload the table(in turn making the API call) when I receive any update on the web socket.

```
    class TableExp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

this.state = {
  tableData: [
    {
      resourceID: '',
      resourceType: '',
      tenantName: '',
      dealerID: '',
      status: '',
      logFilePath: '',
      supportPerson: '',
      lastUpdatedTime: '',
    },
  ],
  //testMessage: [{ message: 'Initial Message' }],
};
}

    componentDidMount() {
this.websocket = new WebSocket(socket);

this.websocket.onopen = () => {
  axios.get('https://myapi.com', {
    headers: {},
    responseType: 'json',
  })
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ tableData: response.data });
  });
  console.log('Socket Opened');
};

this.websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
    const data = (JSON.parse(event.data));
    const status = data.status;
    console.log(data.status);
    this.forceUpdate();

  if (status === 'failed') {
      console.log('Error message received');
      this.reloadTable();
    }
};

this.websocket.onclose = () => {
  this.statusDispatcher('closed');
};
}

 reloadTable() {
  this.forceUpdate();
}

render() {
  const { tableData } = this.state;

return (
  <ReactTable
      data={tableData}
      noDataText="Loading.."
      columns={[
        {
          columns: [
            {
              Header: 'Dealer ID',
              accessor: 'dealerId',
              id: "dealerId",
            },
            {
              Header: 'Location',
              id: "dealerId",
            },
          {
          columns: [
            {
              filterable: false,
              Header: 'File Path',
              accessor: 'logFilePath',
            },
             {
              filterable: false,
              Header: 'Date',
              accessor: 'Date',
            },
          ],
        },
      ]}
      defaultPageSize={20}
      style={{
        height: '450px', // This will force the table body to overflow and scroll, since there is not enough room
      }}
      className="-striped -highlight"
  />
);
}
```

Comment: According to your code, I can see that you are updating your `state.tableData`. Your table should be updated after data are fetched, so what is your problem ?

Comment: Yes, the flow goes like this. I load the page, the table loads the data from an API and starts a web socket connection. My question is, how to reload the table upon receiving an event from the web socket? As soon as i listen to an event on the socket, I need to call the API and reload the table with the new data. Thats the part which isnt working.

Comment: Where is the `forceUpdate` function?

Comment: Its under the this.websocket.onmessage() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple `setState` within `onmessage`

```html
this.websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
  let data = [];
  const status = data.status;

  if (status === 'failed') {
    console.log('Error message received');
    // And do nothing, or empty table
  } else {
    data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  }
  
  this.setState({ tableData: data });
};
```

Comment: I tried the above but I got the error as follows,
Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function
    at ReactTable.getDataModel (app.js:150881)
    at ReactTable.componentWillReceiveProps (app.js:150528)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent

Comment: Is your `data` now as you expected? Seems `data` is now a Hash, not an Array

Comment: I updated my code using the above solution. My bad, I forgot to include, let data = []; With this included, the table reloads. But it becomes empty and I get a loading.. sign , indicating the table reloaded but it hasnt made the API call and hence its unable to populate the rows with data.

Comment: My bad too, we should assign `data` if `status` is not failed. Updated the answer

Comment: I updated my code according to your code above but I still get the same error. ReactTable.getDataModel (app.js:150881) at ReactTable.componentWillReceiveProps (app.js:150528) at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent